# Docker Mounting removes existing file in directory

Tags: docker

I have a docker image whose context in directory `/workspace` is

```
# ls workspace
dir1  dir2
```

When I am mounting a volume in docker's `/workspace` directory this content is lost. Is there any way to retain these files?

```
# docker run command
docker run -d -t --net host --rm \
     -v $PWD:/workspace -w /workspace/workspace_1 \
     my_docker_image:latest /bin/bash
```

At this point content of directory is changes

```
# ls workspace
hostdir1  hostdir2
```

What I want to have is

```
# ls workspace
dir1  dir2  hostdir1  hostdir2
```

Comment: When you mount a directory (or filesystem) on top of another directory, it masks any files that were already there. There's no way to produce a "merged" view the way you've described. A typical solution would be to have an `ENTRYPOINT` script that is responsible for copying files into `/workspace` from another location (e.g., `/workspace.template` or something).